# PHPUnit - how to turn an error for calling a method on a non-set object into a failing test instead of an error

Tags: php, design-patterns, phpunit

I have a class, which uses the Chain of Responsibility pattern. In a nutshell, under certain conditions, if one of its methods is called, it passes the call onto the same method of a successor (it and the successor share the same interface).

Example:

```
catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        if(isset($this->successor))
        {
            $this->successor->log($log);
        }
    }
```

Basically, if the successor has been set, it is given the call. If not, nothing happens.

At the moment, in my Unit test, I have two tests: in one of them, the successor is set and the method is called under the right conditions to trigger the call to the successor. The successor is a mock and I can test that the right method is called.

Now, before writing the `if` statement, I duplicated the same test, but removed the code that sets the successor object. When I run the test, not surpisingly, the test stops with an error because the SUT is trying to call a method on an object that doesn't exist.

When I implement the code (like above) all the tests pass fine.

I am unhappy though. I follow TDD metholodogy and I would like to be able to see a failing test before I write code, not an error.

How can I refactor that so I can have a failing test first, instead of an error?

Comment: A failed test means, that something different happens, to what was expected. An error means, that something is not just unexpected, but it's broken. I recommend to still treat errors as errors. In your case it's even the test, that is broken, because (as it seems) you _allow_ `null` as property, but you don't handle it properly.

Comment: To add to the comment above: TDD says write minimal code that will make your test fail. It means no error happens during testing. Otherwise you'd end up with silly tests that check if a class exists, a method is defined and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is unavoidable. PHP raises a fatal error ([`E_FATAL_ERROR`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)) which kills the process. PHPUnit cannot intercept it to produce an error or failure, nor can your code.

```
$ php -r 'try { $o = null; $o->foo(); } catch (Exceptiion $e) { echo "fail"; }'

Fatal error: Call to a member function foo() on a non-object in Command line code on line 1
```

The most you can do is detect the error in a [shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and dump some diagnostic output. There is no way to recover from a fatal error. :(

As for TDD, I believe the goal is to write as much test code to get your tests to *not pass*. It may seem like a subtle distinction, but that means fail (`F`) or error (`E`) or die (stop running). Once you get there, write code to make the tests pass.

Comment: I see. I thought TDD required writing just a stub, and then writing tests. But you're saying a small level of functionality is allowed, to make the tests fail, rather than throw an error?

Comment: Starting from working code (compiles, runs, and passes all tests), you write just enough test code such that the tests fail to pass. In languages like Java that tends to mean it doesn't compile. In PHP it may mean the process dies due to a fatal error. In both, an error or failure in a test is acceptable as well. Then you write just enough production code to get the tests to pass. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: So, an error in a test is acceptable, *before* the code written to make the test past is written?

Comment: Yes, an error when running the test means it doesn't pass. That's the point you fix the error in the production code so the tests pass.

Answer (score -1):

Place your unit tests into a TRY-CATCH-block. If you catch an exception you can convert it into an failure:

```
try {
    ...testing
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->assertTrue(false, $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: -1 This won't work because calling a method on a non-object results in a fatal error--not an exception.